# Possible to load multiple Google scripts in one file

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-analytics, google-custom-search

I was just wondering if anyone knew how - or if it's even possible - to load multiple Google scripts in one file?  See because on some of my pages I'm loading up to three or more Google scripts:

1. Google Analytics
2. Google CSE
3. Google Maps
4. (once in a while) Google Webfonts

Trying to cut back on HTTP requests and would like to be able to load something like **google.js** that included all of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't download combined js files from Google as a single http request, but you can download, combine and load them your own website provided you update them often enough (like with a cron job twice a day for example). You can even set caching headers if you wish.

Despite all that I would advice against doing it - just load those scripts asynchronously (but from within html, not separate file) - it's non-blocking and will not slow down rendering start of your website.

Answer (score 2):

You can load scripts asynchronously, as it is done in [**this example**](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async). The load function can be modified to accept a URL parameter, such as:

```
function loadScript(url) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = url;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
      }
```

and then:

```
var url =  'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false';
loadScript(url);

var url =  'https://www.somedomain.com/someScript.js';
loadScript(url);

// ...etc
```

Then you can put all this in your separate google.js file. However, while it may become easier to load a bunch of scripts where needed, this does not cut back on HTTP requests.

Comment: This actually would add one http request - to google.js - the opposite of what OP ask for.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in my answer. :-)

Comment: Ah, sorry. This has to be your typical out of caffeine error on my side :P